# Evaluating postfix expression. pop() returns incorrect values to calculate function

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-notation

I am writing a program that converts infix to postfix (through a stack implememnted by linked list), stored in a character array and evaluate the postfix expression. Works fine till conversion.

But when I call the function to evaluate the postfix expression, it gives incorrect answers.

The problem starts at the point where function, evalPfExpression() of class expEvaluator pops a number from the character array of postfix. (highlighted through capital comments in code.)

First it gave completely wrong numbers. But subtracting 48 from each number fixed it for single digits.(noticed every single digit was given with 48 added). But it still gives wrong answers for 2 digit or higher numbers. 
I guess it might have something to do with converting between "char" and "int" types.

Would appreciate the help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

////The node of the stack:
class node   
{
 public:
char value;
node* next;
}; 


////The basic stack class:
class stack 
{
 public:
int size;
node* top;
stack() //default constructor for stack
{
    size=0;
    top=NULL;
}

void push(char);
char pop();
char topstack();
void print();
bool isEmpty();
};


//Stack's push function:
void stack::push(char e)
{
node *temp; 
temp =new node;
temp->next = top;
temp->value=e;
top=temp;
size++;
}
//Stack's pop function:
char stack::pop()
{    
char d;
if (isEmpty())
{
    cout<<"\nStack is Empty\n";
    return '!';
}
else
{
    node *temp = top;
    top=top->next;
    d=temp->value;
    delete temp;
    size--;
}
    return d;
}

//Returns a copy of the stack's top element.
char stack::topstack()
{    
if(size==0)
    return '\0';
else
return top->value;
}

//To print the stack's members.
void stack::print()
{    
cout<<"PRINTING STACK\n";
int s=size;
for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
cout<< pop() <<"\n";
}


//Function to determine whether the stack is empty. Returns true for empty.
bool stack::isEmpty()
{
if(size==0)
{
    return true;
}

return false;
}

////Class, the instance of which will convert infix to postfix.
class expEvaluator
{
 public:
char infix[50];
char postfix[50];

int ps; //counter variable to be used for index of the postfix array.
stack s; //The stack through which the operations will be performed.
expEvaluator() //Constructor.
{
    ps=0;
}
bool isOp(char a)//Function to determine whether the character is an operator.
{
    if(a=='+' || a=='-' || a=='*' || a=='/' || a=='^' || a=='%' )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool precedence(char a, char b)//To determine the precedence of operators. True means 'a' is of same or lower precedence than 'b'.
{
    if(a=='+' || a=='-')
        return true;
    else if (a=='*' || a=='/')
    {
        if(b=='+' || b=='-')
            return false;
        else if(b=='*' || b=='/')
            return true;
    }
}
//The function that will convert the given infix statement to postfix.
void convertToPostfix()
{
    int l=0; //To keep count of the number of characters entered in infix form.

    cout<<"Enter Infix expression: ";
    cin>>infix;

    for(int i=0; infix[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        l++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(infix[i]=='(')
            s.push(infix[i]);
        else if(isOp(infix[i])) //If character at infix[i] is an operator
        {
            while(isOp(s.topstack()) && precedence(infix[i], s.topstack())) //popping operators from stack to postfix array till operator of
            {                                                               //lower precedence is met.
                    postfix[ps]=s.pop();
                    ps++;
            }
        s.push(infix[i]); //then push the operator onto the stack.
        }
        else if(infix[i]==')') //if right bracket encountered.
        {
            while(s.topstack()!='(') //till left bracket is not encountered,
            {
                postfix[ps]=s.pop(); 
                ps++; //keep popping elements to postfix array.
            }
            s.pop(); //pop left bracket when encountered.
        }
        else //if just an operand is encountered.
        {
            postfix[ps]=infix[i]; //copy to postfix array.
            ps++;
        }
    }
    while(!(s.isEmpty())) //When end of array is reached (the previous loop ends only then) and its not empty,
    {
        postfix[ps]=s.pop(); //pop all elements from stack onto the postfix array.
        ps++;
    }
    postfix[ps]='\0';
    cout << "POSTFIX:\n" << postfix;
}

//Function to calculate the result, when two operands and operator are passed to it.
    int calculate(int op1, int op2, char operand)
    {
        if(operand == '+')
        {
             return op1 + op2;
        }
        else if(operand == '-')
        {
            return op1 - op2;
        }
        else if(operand == '*')
        {
            return op1 * op2;
        }
        else if(operand == '/')
        {
            return op1 / op2;
        }
        else if(operand == '%')
        {
            return op1 % op2;
        }
        else if(operand == '^')
        {
            return op1 ^ op2;
        }           
    }

//Function to evaluate the postfix expression:
void evalPfExpression() 
{
    ps = 0;
    while(postfix[ps]!='\0')
    {

        if (!isOp(postfix[ps]))
        {
            s.push(postfix[ps]);
            ps++;
        }
        else if(isOp(postfix[ps]))
        {//******NOT POPPING CORRECT VALUES.******
            int x = s.pop() - 48; //Second operand.
            int y = s.pop() - 48; //First operand.
            cout << "Second operand: "<< x << " First op:" << y << endl;
            int res = calculate(y, x, postfix[ps]);  //The result of two operands calculation
            s.push(res);                             //is returned to the variable 'res' and pushed 
            ps++;                                    //to the stack
        }
    }
    int result = s.pop(); //When '\0' is encountered, loop stops and the final      result is popped
    cout << "\nThe postfix statement evaluates to:\n" << result << endl;
}


};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(void)
{
expEvaluator e1;
e1.convertToPostfix();
e1.evalPfExpression();

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with pop(). It is popping what you are pushing. The problem is with what you are pushing.

1. If you want values larger than 255 you will have to use 'int', not 'char' as the value type in the node.
2. You are pushing the *character* itself, not its *value.* For example, you are pushing '0', not 0. The difference between them is, guess what? 48.
3. For multi-digit numbers you need to push the result of some function such as atoi() on the *string* you want to parse as a number.

Comment: 1. Since I also have to use the stack's nodes for the operators, I'll have to do with this limitation.
2. So I should add 48 with each push statement's argument?
3. Will the atoi() function accept an element of character array as a string? How will it work?
Thanks for helping out.

Comment: No, you should subtract it. Actually subtract '0'. Or use atoi() as documented.